# Is there a way to delete MX records from a Cloudflare App?

Tags: cloudflare-apps

I'm working on an app that updates the site's MX records to redirect mail for the site to our servers.  I'd like to be able to remove the MX records we add when the site is uninstalled, since at that point we'll stop accepting mail for the domain.  It seems like other record types, such as TXT, are removed on uninstall, but MX records are not.  Is there a way I can remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug, which has since been fixed.  MX records are now correctly removed when the app is uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

`MX` records should be removed with an uninstall as well. Did the zone you test on have the `mx` record prior to installing the app? Have you tested with multiple zones? I recommend creating a test zone (doesn't have to be active) and not adding any mx records then see what happens.

Comment: I've just verified the behaviour.  On a zone with no MX records, if I install, it correctly adds two MX records and a TXT record.  On uninstall, the TXT record is removed, but the MX records remain.

Comment: What is the name of your app? Can you submit the app through the app previewer so I can see the code?